# Format DateTime without string conversion

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I'm revising some legacy code and there is this...

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

DateTime from = DateTime.Parse(dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00"));
DateTime to = DateTime.Parse(dateTime.AddDays(8).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59"));
```

The from and to variables are then used in Linq / Lambda comparisons, so must be a DateTime.

I can't seem to find a way to format a DateTime variable without converting it to a string, and then back to a DateTime, this seems daft to say the least.

Surely there must be a way to format a DateTime without converting it to a string and then back to a DateTime?

Comment: `DateTime` has no "format" unless it's converted to a `string`

Comment: Thank to both Soner and Habib... couldn't see the wood for the trees ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to convert your `DateTime` to string and then parse it back to `DateTime`, instead use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
DateTime from = dateTime.Date;
DateTime to = dateTime.Date.AddDays(9).AddTicks(-1); //or .AddSeconds(-1) if you want 
                                                     // accuracy to a second.
```

Comment: @DStanley, thanks, but just before you comment, I *remembered* :)\

Comment: Minor point but dateTime.Date.AddDays(8).AddTicks(-1) gives {13/11/2014 23:59:59} whereas DateTime.Parse(dateTime.AddDays(8).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59")); gives {14/11/2014 23:59:59}

Answer (score 3):

A [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. String representations of it have. And [`Today` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sets time part to midnight.

```
DateTime from = DateTime.Today;
DateTime to   = DateTime.Today.AddDays(9).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Comment: Minor point but DateTime.Today.AddDays(8).AddSeconds(-1) gives {13/11/2014 23:59:59} whereas DateTime.Parse(dateTime.AddDays(8).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 23:59:59")); gives {14/11/2014 23:59:59}